# Да что такое-то?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Word предлагает писать фразу "*Да что такое-то?*" с двумя дефисами, то есть в виде "*Да что-такое-то?*". По-моему, так полный бред, но вдруг я чего-то не понимаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно говорят: ***А что такого-то?***

Имеется в виду: что тут такого особенного?

**Частица ТО пишется через дефис**,  после местоимения ЧТО дефиса не требуется.

**-ТО, частица.** 1. Употр. **для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится.** Я-то понимаю. Ночь-то какая тёплая! Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял. Где-то он сейчас? Что дальше-то делать будешь?
2. Входит в состав неопределённых местоимений и наречий. Кто-то звонит. Что-то упало со стола.

Comment: "_Что такое_" и "_что такого_" - это разные обороты с разным значением, давайте все же не будем их смешивать. Насчет частицы "то" никаких сомнений и не было. Собственно, достаточно было подтвердить мои подозрения, что проверка грамматики в Ворде бредовая и к его рекомендациям стоит относиться с осторожностью.

Comment: Sharon, у *"А что такого-то?"* смысл *"Ну что ж тут особенного?",* а у *"Да что такое-то?"* — *"Ну в чём же дело?! Ничего не получается!"*

Comment: Спасибо, Артем. Я просто обычно говорю "да что же это такое". Фраза "да что такое-то" мне кажется немного странной, но это, наверное, на любителя. Что касается программы, то "бредовость" предложенного варианта не вызывает сомнения. Интересно, почему ошиблась программа. Возможно,  это неправильное совмещение двух форм: что-то и такое-то.

Comment: Да, возможно. Но Word очень часто находит непонятные ошибки и предлагает странные варианты.